# Mapping and looping in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, lambda, split

I want to create a function that displays the argument to the function (the "sentence") and then lists the number of characters of each word in the functions argument below each word. This is a personal curiosity rather than a practical use, I'm not concerned with word wraps. I won't know how many words are in the sentence.

The end results to be

```
The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog
3   5     5     3   5     3   4    3
```

This is what I have so far... but I'm not sure how to iterate the lengths and format the spacing between the "lengths". The last line is a hard-coded failed attempt to accomplish the goal above.

```
sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog'
words = sentence.split()
#print words


lengths = map(lambda word: len(word), words)
print lengths
print sentence
print str(lengths[0]).ljust(lengths[0]+1) + str(lengths[1]).ljust(lengths[1]+1) + str(lengths[2]).ljust(lengths[2]+1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good stackoverflow question. Your question should be technical and specific - not help me code X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nearly there. `ljust` is a great function to use. You just need to write a list comprehension that will create each justified string from each length.

eg.

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog"
words = sentence.split()
# this is a list comprension
# you can create a new list by applying functions to each element in the list.
word_lengths = [len(w) for w in words]
word_length_strings = [str(l).ljust(l) for l in word_lengths]
# now you have a list of strings that start with a number and are left padded 
# with spaces to that number.
assert len(words[0]) == len(word_length_strings[0])
# and to join the words up in to one line
line = ' '.join(word_length_strings)
print(sentence)
print(line)
```

Comment: I like how this solution accounts for words that are greater than 10 characters in length.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def func():
...     sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog"
...     words = sentence.split()    
...     print sentence
...     for wordlen in map(len, words):
...         print wordlen, " "*(wordlen-1-len(str(wordlen))),  # the comma terminates the print with a single white space (instead of newline)
... 
>>> func()
The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog
3   5     5     3   5     3   4    3
```

Comment: The question specifically states that the sentece is "an argument to the function." More like def func(sentence): ...

Answer (score 2):

```
def num_of_chars(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    lengths = map(lambda word: len(word), words)
    print sentence+'\n'+''.join([str(l)+' '*(l-len(str(l))+1) for l in lengths])


>>> sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog'

>>> num_of_chars(sentence)

The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog
3   5     5     3   5     3   4    3
```

Comment: This is good but should be incorporated into a function as per the OPs request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that involves passing the sentence to a method.

```
def printSentence(inSentence):
    wordList = sentence.split()
    charCount = [len(word) for word in wordList]

    print(str(wordList).replace(']', '').replace('[', '').replace(',', '\t').replace("'", ""))
    print(str(charCount).replace(']', '').replace('[', '').replace(',', '\t').replace("'", ""))

sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog' 
printSentence(sentence)       

>>> 
The  quick   brown   fox     jumps   the     lazy    dog
3    5       5       3       5       3       4       3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd build a function to split each word, then `str.join` a list comp together for the numbers. Something like:

```
def length_mapping(s):
    lengths = map(len, s.split())
    result = "\n".join( [s, "".join([str(length) + ' '*length for length in lengths])] )
    return result
```

More verbose:

```
def length_mapping_verbose(s):

    words = s.split() # get words from the sentence

    lengths = [] # initialize an empty list to store lengths in
    for word in words:
        lengths.append(len(word))
    # this is exactly:
    # # lengths = [len(word) for word in words]

    length_string = ""
    for length in lengths:
        length_string += str(length)
        length_string += " " * length
        # the number plus an amount of spaces equal to the number.
        # this only works for single-digit word lengths.
        # "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" will break this! We'll fix it later

    result = s + "\n" + length_string
    return result
```

As I mentioned before, very long words will break this, since we'll get results like this

```
some short words with an unimaginably-large word in the middle
4    5     5     4    2  18                  4    2  3   6
```

Notice how the lengths to the right of the double-digit-length word get displaced by an extra space? This is an off-by-one error caused by the fact that we're not counting the length ***of the length***, we're just assuming it's one to allow for the space afterwards. To fix it we could do:

```
def length_mapping_safe(s):
    lengths = map(len, s.split())
    result = "\n".join( [s, " ".join([str(length) + " " * (length - len(str(length)) for length in lengths])] )
    return result
```

That is to say:

```
" ".join(                           # join with spaces
    [str(length)                    # a list of strings, each starting a length
     + ' ' *                        # plus a number of spaces equal to...
         (length - len(str(length)) # the length minus the number of digits IN that length
    for length in lengths])         # for each length in the string lengths
```

Alternatively you could do something with string formatting like:

```
def length_mapping_with_str_format(s):
    word_formatter = "{{:{}}}"
    words = s.split()
    lengths = [str(len(word)) for word in words]
    lengths_as_words = [word_formatter.format(L).format(L) for L in lengths]
    result = "\n".join([s, " ".join(lengths_as_words)])
```